# AMQ119099: Unable to authenticate cluster user: ACTIVEMQ.CLUSTER.ADMIN.USER

Tags: wildfly-10

When I was starting Wildfly 10 with full-ha profile, I was getting below error in the log file.

`AMQ119099: Unable to authenticate cluster user: ACTIVEMQ.CLUSTER.ADMIN.USER`

Even after this error, server was in running state.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was getting this error because I have not changed the default password of subsystem `messaging-activemq`.

This error is gone after changing below line of `domain.xml`

```
<cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:CHANGE ME!!}"/>
```

to

```
<cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:mypass}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's required to specify a password for the cluster of `messaging-activemq` subsystem. It can be set using the following system property when starting the wildfly server:

```
... -Djboss.messaging.cluster.password=Abcd1234
```